# KivMob Ads not showing up, Kivy issuing a warning

Tags: python, android, kivy, admob, kivmob

I have tried troubleshooting this but nothing is really working.

```
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from threading import Thread
import threading

mob = KivMob( 'ca-app-pub-3818132104220327~2137123840')

class AssistantApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10, padding=(10, 10, 10, 10))

        mob.new_banner('ca-app-pub-3818132104220327/8424681662', True)

        self.computer_response_label = Label(text="Ready")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.computer_response_label)

        self.cmp = 'No info'

        self.qlist = []

        mob.request_banner()
        mob.show_banner()

        return self.layout
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AssistantApp().run()
```

Here are my logs:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in \.kivy\logs\kivy_24-01-23_22.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "\Python\Python311\pythonw.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.4575'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 31.0.101.4575'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.5, Python 3.11.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] __init__ called.
[WARNING] [KivMob      ] Ads will not be shown.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] new_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] request_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] show_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

I have removed the irrelevant parts. The kivmobs ads are refusing to show up with my own ids or the test ones.

I have tried different types of ids and moving the request statements around and even removing them but it still issues a warning.

Comment: The ads won't show in the compiler, it only shows on the actual device.

Comment: Yeah, they aren't showing up on the application window either. I think it is due to the warning in the shell.

Comment: So essentially there are no ads showing up, on the window or otherwise. My hypothesis is that it is because of 
[WARNING] [KivMob      ] Ads will not be shown.

Even though
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] new_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] request_banner() called.
[INFO   ] [KivMob      ] show_banner() called.

Comment: It's not going to show on the application window either. It will only show up on the actual device once you compile it into an AAB and run it on your phone.

Comment: Oh, understood. I am on a windows machine and my WSL isn't doing things correctly for some reason so what options are there to compile my Kivy app. I can try PyInstaller.

Comment: You can use Google Colab to compile it. There are many tutorials on YouTube.